# Parsing a .txt file to key/value pairs in Ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, text, hash

I was wondering if anybody could help me out and tell me the best way to parse the following text (from a .txt file) into key value pairs

The text I have to work with is :

```
"This is the Question Line"
"This is the Answer Line"
```

Then it repeats. What would be the easiest way for me to parse these lines and all the ones that come after them and associate them with the Question and Answer keys?

Comment: To specify: I want it to return this:

{Question => "This is the Question Line", Answer => "This is the Answer Line"}

Comment: What have you tried? Specifically, what part of this are you having issues with?

Comment: I have tried, and am able to, read in the entire text file as a String, but I haven't been able to eloquently make it associate the proper lines with the Question and Answer keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
array = []
# open the file in read mode. With block version you don'r need to
# worry about to close the file by hand. It will be closed when the
# read operation will be completed.
File.open('path/to/file', 'r') do |file|
  # each_line gives an Enumerator object. On which I'm calling
  # each_slice to take 2 lines at a time, where first line is the
  # question, and the second one is the answer. 
  file.each_line.each_slice(2).do |question, answer|
    array << {'Question' => question, 'Answer' => answer}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper ruby way is probably something like:

```
data = Hash[['Question','Answer'].zip File.read('input.txt').split("\n")]
```